# Is there a flutter plugin that acts like a file picker and is supported by Google developers?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am in need of a file picker, which supports picking a pdf or an image from the file system.

There is one third party plugin available - 
file picker plugin: `pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker` .

However, I want to know if a plugin supported by Google Developers is there or in development.

I know that there is image picker plugin supported by Google developers. I wish for a File Picker.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) in my projects.
It's quite stable and I didn't find any issue with it.

If you don't want to use any plugin then try using custom **platform-specific** code
See docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

But I recommend better to try for plugin unless it is buggy, rather than inventing your own wheel.

Comment: Hi Mangaldeep, how will path_provider help me pick a file? I thought it is for accessing a file using a specific path. It wont allow me to pick a file using UI

Comment: Sorry, I thought you need the file through your code.

Comment: Yes, file picker plugin is the third party plugin which I referred to in my question.